# I need compiere 3.3 erp database file for postgres db

Tags: postgresql

Could anyone help me with compiere 3.3 database file (.dmp, .sql or anything) that I could use to restore my compiere Postgres database

Answer (score 1):

Just download it from compiere.com or ask them where you can find this verion. It's open source, start your search close to the source: www.compiere.com

Comment: I have downloaded it but for some reasons, I cannot install the db that is why am looking for the file separately. They do not have it on their website